# Unable to run a Spark Java Program

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, bigdata

I am running a Spark Program written in java & I am using the sample wordcount example.
I have created a jar file but, when I am submitting the spark job it is throwing an error.

```
$ spark-submit --class WordCount --master local \ home/cloudera/workspace/sparksample/target/sparksample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I am getting the below error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: wordCount
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:175)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:689)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

**Edited**
i am also adding my pom.xml so that you can help.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.igi.sparksample</groupId>
  <artifactId>sparksample</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
  <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
<groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
<version>1.6.0</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
  <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying so many combinations and doing a bit R&D i solved my issue.
Issue was in my spark submit command i changed it to this

```
spark-submit --class com.xxx.sparksample.WordCount --master local  /home/cloudera/workspace/sparksample/target/sparksample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

and it worked.

Comment: Thanks @ShubhamChaurasia. Upvoted Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It can't find the `WordCount` class. You probably need to include the package that class is in, so you have the full classpath, ie:

`--class <PACKAGE>.WordCount`

Comment: while creating the project in eclipse i didn't gave any package name. It is showing default package.

Comment: Thanks @BinaryNerd

Answer (score 0):

The error you posted doesn't show any problem with Spark.

However, you must have a typo in your program. Java threw a `ClassNotFoundException` looking for `wordCount`, where it should most probably be `WordCount`, with a capital W.

Please check the names of your classes and your imports.

Comment: i changed the name to WordCount but it didn't solve the issue i am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the name of class (wordcount or WordCount or whatever...) that you pass to `spark-submit` is exactly similar to what you have defined. 

Make sure that packaging is correct.

To verify, open/extract your jar and see the class name and the package hierarchy.